# Java exec grep | linux fails

Tags: java, regex, grep

SOLVED SEE COMMENT BELOW

Ok, this one is tricky:

I call this command from Java with `Process.exec()`:

```
grep -ne 'xxx\|yyy' file
```

and it only returns `xxx`?

Edit: I escape the `\` with `\\` in java.

But when I call the exact same command from the commandline on the same machine it returns both `xxx` and `yyy` as expected!?

I have tried everything, escaping more and less with `-E`, changing `'` to `"` (which actually oddly doesn't work when you run from java either)?!

Has someone run in to the exact same odd problem?

Comment: Can you try this command: `grep -ne 'xxx\\|yyy' file` OR `grep -n -e 'xxx' -e 'yyy'  file` ?

Comment: Of course I escape the \ in the java code with \\ othervise this wouldn't work at all.

Comment: If the `|` has to be escaped on the command line, you might have to use 3 or 4 `\ ` characters in your Java string!

Comment: ok SOLVED thanks to anubhava... grep -n -e 'xxx' -e 'yyy' file didnt work but then I tried grep -n -e 'xxx' file and that didnt work either so I tried grep -ne 'xxx\|yyy\|zzz' file and THEN xxx and yyy returned lol

Answer (score 1):

You will have to escape '\' by putting '\\' as follows :

```
.exec("grep -ne 'xxx\\|yyy' file");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might be a dumb question, but why not use BufferedReader/[readLine](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29), and then String.indexOf or other regex, rather than shelling out to grep?

Grep is probably faster than Java at searching the file, but on the other hand, creating a child process from Java would probably negate any benefit gained there.

Comment: Because xxx and yyy are complex and need regexp anyhow + the file is BIG!